# Gae Connect to 3rd party service

Tags: google-app-engine, rabbitmq, couchbase

Can gae connects to other services such as rabbitmq, couchbase, or any other third party system that may have been setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they accept connections using HTTP methods, e.g. POST, GET then yes.

Otherwise no. Sockets are not yet available but there is a beta you can sign up for.

Comment: That means unable to use the official lib clients for couchbase rabbitmq etc?

Comment: If those clients are written in pure python then you can include them in your GAE proejct. If those clients use standard HTTP methods then they will also work! For Java, I don't know what the rules are about what you can and cannot include.

Comment: I just had a quick look at couchbase, they are doing a RESTful interface in version 3 according to a thread on their forum.

Comment: Thank you! Now wondering if google allows us to do this instead of using their memcache etc :)

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want to do such a thing but there you go.

Comment: Because existing system writes to rabbitmq, and intend to create a gae app to process the queue. If switch to task queue, much higher latency is incurred for existing system to write to task queue rather than local rabbitmq. So thinking of using gae cron to process rabbitmq.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but at the moment only via HTTP requests. See the [URL Fetch Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/http://).